# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - VPC grayed out while trying to change the settings of an already created VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I cannot modify the VPC settings in the elastic beanstalk configuration:

[image: I cannot modify the VPC settings in the elastic beanstalk configuration]

I tried changing the config but the button is grayed out. I know it is using the default VPC but I cannot change it to another one.

The Elastic Beanstalk has been running for months, I just created a new VPC with all its configs (subnets, Internet Gateway, routes, etc). I can create a new EB and add it to the VPC but if I try to modify my already existing EB and change its VPC, the option is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

That's as intended.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.vpc.html#environments-cfg-vpc-console-vpc

> Choose a VPC for your environment. You can only change this setting during environment creation.

To change VPCs, you'll need to make a new ElasticBeanstalk instance.